# How to get the table name from a `DataObject`?

Tags: apache-cayenne

A table `my_table` should have a generated class named `MyTable`. How do I get the table name, `my_table`, from Cayenne while having access to `MyTable`?

I'm not looking for snake_case <=> CamelCase that kind of approach. I'm looking for something like `MyTable.TABLE_NAME` (not exists) or `Cayenne.getTableName(MyTable.class)` (not exists either).

(using Cayenne 4.2.RC2)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from Cayenne metadata:

```
String tableName = objectContext
  .getEntityResolver()
  .getObjEntity(MyTable.class)
  .getDbEntityName();
```