# How to `delete from MY_TABLE`?

Tags: apache-cayenne

`cayenneContext.deleteObjects(ObjectSelect.query(MyTable.class).select(cayenneContext));` is not very efficient for many objects.

Is there anything elegant like `ObjectDelete.delete(MyTable.class)` that I failed to discover?

`SQLExec.query("delete from MY_TABLE").execute(cayenneContext);` is fine, if no better way to do it. But I'd need to know the table name for this (I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75048462/1066506) for that).

Answer (score 0):

Selecting objects first to delete them is the ORM way to keep the in-memory object graph consistent (and to process delete rules, callbacks, etc.). But yeah, it is not very efficient for large batches.

`SQLExec` would be the recommended way to do it directly in the DB. And I answered your other question about the table name.